# C# Is it appropiate to use IEnumerator Coroutines in Unity for the application's logic flow?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, logic, coroutine

I am developing in Unity using C#, and would like to ask if it is appropriate to use IEnumerator Coroutines to determine an application's execution of user logic? And if there are any other optimal solutions to implement this.

To clarify as a series of strict sequential actions...

1. User triggers GUI action.
2. Open Form, and waits until it is filled out.
3. Begins checking if winning condition is satisfied in task (4.), if completed, jump to (5.)
4. Series of sequential tasks for user to complete, returns a result back to (3.) after a cycle is complete. Keep cycling between stages (3.) and (4.) until winning condition is satisfied.
5. Winning condition is met, inform user of final result. Exit co-routine.

I do hope that my logic is sound, and apologies for the vagueness of the specific task involved.

Comment: Is "yes/no" the answer you want? If so then yes!

Comment: @Programmer Yes / No is definitely an answer for me to be satisfied, but it would mean more to me if I was told a better method exists and the reason behind it.

Answer (score 2):

Using coroutines is completely fine for the right reasons. Although from what i read what you are making is a manager that checks the state of the game.

What i would do in that case is having a simple manager that doesn't utilize the update loop or coroutines at all, instead any gameobject which can change the state of the game tells the manager about the change. By basically turning it around the manager does not have to know a single game object and also doesn't use any performance to check all the relevant objects.

Using this architecture you could also add an event handler architecture which solves the problem of gameobjects knowing the manager, now you have a completely decoupled manager from the game :)

Comment: I definitely did not think about it that way, thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1):

While what you have in mind is certainly possible, it will be hard to maintain once you will have multiple winning conditions, perhaps losing conditions, and more than one player.

If you think that this will be an issue for you, I suggest making a "game state" as a singleton, and allow different game objects to change the status within their respective Update() calls.

(I would also like to point out that creating singletons in unity is rather easy - during Awake() save the object itself as a static variable)